# Simulating Fibonacci's Rabbits with multiple offsprings using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

Suppose I start with one pair of rabbit and each pair reproduces 3 pairs of rabbits.
 Let new rabbit pair be `N` and mature rabbit pair be `M`:

```
 N    0 
 M    1
MNNN  4
MNNN MMM MMM MMM 19
```

So the series is `0 1 4 19`

How do we do this on Python using loops:

I tried:

```
x="N" #new rabbit pair
x=x.replace("N","M")
x
'M' #Mature rabbit pair
x=x.replace("M","MNNN")
x
'MNNN'
x=x.replace("M","MN")
x=x.replace("N","M")
x
'MNNNMMM'
```

How do I put this in a loop using xrange/range function.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I'd expect step 4 to be `'MNNNMMM'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for a single step is to replace all `'M'`s with `'MNNN'` and all `'N'`s with `'M'`, so:

```
def step(state):
    return ''.join(['MNNN' if s == 'M' else 'M' for s in state])
```

For example:

```
>>> s = 'N'
>>> for _ in range(5):
    print s, len(s)
    s = step(s)


N 1
M 1
MNNN 4
MNNNMMM 7
MNNNMMMMNNNMNNNMNNN 19
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonrsharpe... This method is very quick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
mature = 'M'
kid = 'N'
start = 'N'
for i in range(10):
    ms = start.count(mature)
    start = start.replace(kid ,mature)
    start = start + kid * (ms * 3)
    print(start)
```

For performance and memory usage - you can use -

```
mature = 'M'
kid = 'N'
start = (0,1)
print(mature * start[0] + kid * start[1])
for i in range(10):
    newmature = start[1] 
    newkid = start[0] * 3
    start = (start[0] + newmature , start[1] + newkid - newmature)
    print(mature * start[0] + kid * start[1] + " - " + str(start[0] + start[1]))
```

Comment: Why do you bother assigning, then not using, `mature` and `kid`? This doesn't maintain order, although that may not be important.

Comment: Oh sorry, I intended to use it, instead of 'M' and 'N' , so that if those are replaced in the future its easy to replace.

Comment: It's very slow though if you increase the iterations. Is there any faster way since its consuming too much memory ?

Comment: With respect to memory this would only store an extra 'M' and 'N' strings, which should be 4 bytes at max than the required amount of memory, if you want you can think about a way for which you are not storing anything in memory at all,. Let me make it up and update in the answer.